# Parse comma separated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to parse comma separated values from a url parameter in Ruby on Rails.

For example how to parse the following?

```
http://example.com/?fields=1,2,3
```

I would like to be able to use params[:fields] in my controller. Is that creating an array? Should I use for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foo = params[:fields].split(',')
```

Comment: What if its only 1a value? Will that produce an error? What is the most efficient way to iterate over foo?

Comment: Nope, it won't produce an error.  Splitting a string with no delimiters present just returns an array with one element.  If you want to perform an action for each element, using #each to iterate is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks chron for your comment

Answer (score 3):

```
> a = "1,2,3"
 => "1,2,3" 
> a.split(',')
 => ["1", "2", "3"] 
> a.split(',').each {|element| p element}
"1"
"2"
"3"
 => ["1", "2", "3"] 
> a.split(',').map(&:to_i)
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo = params[:fields].split(',').map { |i| Integer(i) }`

This will convert the fields params to integers and will validate your fields params if you want them to be integers.An Argument error will raise if that's not the case.(ex. http://example.com/?fields=1,2,test)

Answer (score 0):

## extract_value (Rails 7.1+)

Rails 7.1 introduced a new method called [`extract_value`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-extract_value), which does exactly what you need, it returns parameter value for the given `key` separated by `delimiter`.

So now, you can write something like the following:

```
fields = params.extract_value(:fields)

fields = params.extract_value(:fields, delimiter: ",")
```

**Sources:**

- [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-extract_value).
- [GitHub PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49042).